# Python - Replace with null with 0 and check if less than

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to check for nulls, replace them with zero and the check if the value is less than 5

From some research 
`#df = df[df['speed'] < 5]`
will remove records that are greater than 5
and 
`#df.fillna(0) will replace nulls`

I have tried 
`df = df[df[df['speed'].fillna(0, inplace=True)]< 5]`
however it returns an index error, I expect it needs to be done in steps

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you share your input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) - with `fillna` without `inplace=True`, because `inplace` return `None`:

```
df[df['speed'].fillna(0) < 5]
```

Another solution:

```
df[(df['speed'] < 5) | df['speed'].isna()]
```

If need `inplace` operation use 2 steps, but `NaN`s are replaced by `0` in filtered `DataFrame`:

```
df['speed'].fillna(0, inplace=True)

df[df['speed'] < 5]
```